# Case Sensitive Error with javascript file

Tags: javascript, case-sensitive, samsung-smart-tv

We have created and uploaded Samsung Smart TV app. And we have getting this case sensitive error :

> "File Included in App Source code
>   http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js might be case sensitive or
>   is not included in app [ filename:null funcName: line: code: ] ".

What is this mean?

Comment: The provided info is insufficient. JavaScript is case sensitive as is, but the error you mentioned looks like a custom one. Try searching for `might be case sensitive or is not included in` in your application's code to figure out what's happening.

Comment: Thanks man! I will do it. We are running the app in different environments. Can it be one of the reasons?

Comment: I doubt that, case-sensitivity is a thing which is very well implemented on all engines, so switching brosers/OS shouldn't affect the behaviour. It *should* behave the same regarding this. But it's just a guess or a tip where to start, I've never worked with Samsung Smart TVs.

Comment: What the framework? Is it pure web app (html+javascript) or a wrapper like phonegap?

Comment: It is pure web app,but also we are using smartbox

Comment: If you mean [this project](https://github.com/immosmart/smartbox) then it is not an error from it. I am confused by `File Included in App Source code`. This is not an error from browser. You're using some custom library or framework or wrapper...

Comment: You are right,we are using that project and yes,I know,it isn't from the smartbox

Answer (score 1):

Samsungdforum app policy specify, that you should not use external sources for your app. (I can't find link at this moment, site is often changes)

You can download this file, save it in your source directory and include it by relative path.

This error message may occur because validation tool may expect relative urls and can not load http links. But this is just my speculation.